# how to use Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString() and Base64.encodeBase64String() together in single file

Tags: java

I have a jsp file, in which I need to use to methods of class Base64.
one method is present in java.util :

```
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString().
```

and another method is present in

```
    org.apache.commons.codec.binary package :
    org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String()
```

so to achieve this I used fully classified names but still it is givng error.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An
>   error occurred at line: 59 in the jsp file: /ProcessDetails.jsp
>   org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 cannot be resolved to a type
>   56: String signature =
>   java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doF‌​inal(data.getBytes()‌​));
>   59: String paymentToken =
>   org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(sh‌​a256_HMAC.doFinal(da‌​ta.getBytes()));

Comment: "but still it is givng error" - what error?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please don't add relevant informations (error messages and code) to comments, but to the question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be missing either the apache commons jar in your WEB-INF/lib 
see [jsp "unable to compile" and "cannot be resolved to a type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985271/jsp-unable-to-compile-and-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

or perhaps a missing import statement in your JSP
see [Unable to compile class for JSP: cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502412/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Hope that helps